# Python fill empty cells in dataframe based on the values of other column values and conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have the following problem set which I have spent days on trying to find the optimal solution:

giving a country evaluating process having 3 parameters (V1,V2,V3), which may be recorded in sperate dates (Date1,Date2,Date3) repsectively, each record of a single parameter is stored in one row, with date and value, as illustrated in the picture below.

I need to fill empty cells in a row with two parameters recorded in other rows based on two rules

1. for the country (ISO), and the recorded parameter in current row, if the other two parameters' recordings of the same country exist in the table in other rows, chose the recorded parameter value/date for the same country in other rows with the date most close to the parameter recording date in current row.
2. otherwise, if the same country doesn't have other one or two parameters recorded in other rows yet, use the recorded parameter value and date in the current row to fill the empty cells of the other two parameters in the current row.

for example:

Record NO.1, country "AND" only have one parameter V1 recorded in the table (C2,D2), thus, (E2,F2) and (G2,H2) should be filled with value from  (C2,D2),as 123 and 2022/4/12

Record NO.2, Country "COR" has only one V2 recorded (E3,F3), and two V1 recorded in Record NO.4 and NO.5, then, in Record NO.2, V1(C3,D3) should be filled with value in Record NO.5 (C6,D6), since Record NO.5's date (D6,2022.07.12) is most close to Record NO.2(D3,2022.07.13).

The process has to loop through the dataframe to fill all the empty cells. [image]Please HELP!

Comment: in your example, how should lines 4,5 be filled? Should V3, Date3 lines 2 be filled in?

Comment: in  lines 4,5, (V2,D2,V3,D3 ) should be filled with  value of V2 and D 2 in line 2, because line 2 and 4,5 all below to the same country COR

Comment: should (G3,H3) row 2 be written as value #5 (C6,D6)?

Comment: @inquirer yes, because it has a close date to row 2 (G3,H3)

Comment: Records for example COR can be more than 3?    AND so if there are two values, which one to choose?

Comment: Yes, it can be many, when the COR has more than one record of one parameter of different date, chose the one has the closest date into the calculation, if there are more than two in the same date, chose the largest value into the calculation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249271/discussion-between-pepin-peng-and-inquirer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way I can think of without looping over the whole dataset each time you encounter an empty value. With that in mind, this could take a while to run if the file size is large. You may have to switch out date formats if excel auto formats the date differently.

```py
import pandas
from datetime import datetime

pd = pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=r"path/to/csv")

dt_format = '%Y/%m/%d'
# dt_format = '%m/%d/%Y'


for index, row in pd.iterrows():
    checks = [pandas.isnull(row['V1']), pandas.isnull(row['V2']), pandas.isnull(row['V3'])]
    empties = [i + 1 for i in range(0, 3) if checks[i]]
    reference = checks.index(False) + 1
    closest = None
    for empty in empties:
        iso = row['ISO']
        # Create timestamp of date of the filled in Date column
        ts = datetime.strptime(row[f'Date{reference}'], dt_format).timestamp()
        for index2, row2 in pd.iterrows():
            if row2['ISO'] == iso and not pandas.isnull(row2[f'V{empty}']):
                if closest is None:
                    closest = (row2[f'V{empty}'], row2[f'Date{empty}'])
                else:
                    delta1 = abs(datetime.strptime(closest[1], dt_format).timestamp() - ts)
                    delta2 = abs(datetime.strptime(row2[f'Date{empty}'], dt_format).timestamp() - ts)
                    if delta2 < delta1:
                        closest = (row2[f'V{empty}'], row2[f'Date{empty}'])
        if closest is not None:
            pd.at[index, f'V{empty}'] = closest[0]
            pd.at[index, f'Date{empty}'] = closest[1]

pd.to_csv(r"path/to/csv")
```

Comment: hi@Nick, this codes work fine, I test it initially with smaller datasets, and it reached what I need, I will see how will large datasets run on this code. Thank you for your contribution !!